# How To Get 360 Panorama Equirectangular In Blender Internal Render?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, camera, panoramic

I wanted to know, how to render 360 panorama equirectangular like in cycles render... to post it on Facebook and get 360 image feature, but I want to render it on internal render this time

360 Panorama Equirectangular:
[image: Example]